# Linear Algebra - Show that coordinates of u and A are proportional.

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem that I ran into, I'm not even sure how to start it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

A line L in **R**<sup>n</sup> can be represented by parametric equation L(t) = t**u** + A where **u** is a directional vector of the line and A is a point on the line. Suppose that A ≠ **0**. Show that if L is a subspace of **R**<sup>n</sup> then the coordinates of **u** and A are proportional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear subspace has to contain the zero vector. Thus there has to be a value $t_0$ such that $L(t_0) = \boldsymbol 0$ or rather $t_0 \boldsymbol u + \boldsymbol A = \boldsymbol 0$. This already matches a prominent definition of linear dependence. You could also write $t_0 \boldsymbol u = (-1) \boldsymbol A$, which makes the proportionality obvious.

$\boldsymbol u$ and $\boldsymbol A$ being dependent has the same effect on the resulting manifold as choosing $\boldsymbol A = \boldsymbol 0$, i.e. $L(t) = t \boldsymbol u$ which is a linear map.

Comment: Ah, I have it now, thanks for your help!